# Spring Boot JUnit Test Case Getting JPARepository Error

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I was having some problem when trying to write some junit test cases for repository in spring boot. Here is my JUnit Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class RoomRepositoryTest {
@Autowired
private TestEntityManager entityManager;
@Autowired
private RoomRepository roomRepository;

@Test
public void whenFindByRoomNumber_thenReturnRoom() {
    Room room = new Room();
    room.setRoomNumber("P1");
    entityManager.persist(room);
    entityManager.flush();

    Room found = roomRepository.findByRoomNumber(room.getRoomNumber());
    assertEquals(found.getRoomNumber(), room.getRoomNumber());
}
```

And my Repository class:

```
@Repository
public interface RoomRepository extends JpaRepository<Room, Long> {
    Room findByRoomNumber(String roomNumber);
}
```

My pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

However, I am having compilation error

```
Cannot access org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
```

at this line

```
roomRepository.findByRoomNumber
```

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you have some dependency issue (or broken jars). Try `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` then do `mvn verify` (or whatever you use to build) to re download the dependencies. The `@Repository` on the repository is useless it doesn't add anything.

Comment: Hi I did a mvn clean install command on my project root folder but the error still persist

Comment: After you purged the dependencies?

Comment: @M.Deinum yes yes I also invalidate cache and restarted my intellij, but the problem still persist

Comment: Did the `mvn clean install` complete successfully?

Comment: Yes it completed successfully. I tried to call the default function like findAll() provided by JPA also throwing the same error

Comment: So it is an IDE issue not a dependency issue as your code (and test) successfully runs on the cmd line. Maybe wrong JDK? Make sure that Maven uses the project JDK for compiling/dependencies (can be set through the settings in Intellij).

Comment: @M.Deinum Hi I am not able to test successfully as there is a compilation error

Comment: Yes you are as `mvn clean install` works, that also runs tests. With that it is thus an IDE issue.